# CSS3 box-shadow on <li> element not working

Tags: list, css, unordered

I have a grid of 12 boxes created from an unordered list as below. Border radius works fine, but IU can't get the shadow to appear. Does the box-shadow property only work on divs, but not display block elements?

```
   <ul id="treatments">
   <li id="eyelash"></li>
   <li id="massage"></li>
   <li id="tanning"></li>
   <li id="facials"></li>
   <li id="waxing"></li>
   <li id="tinting"></li>
   <li id="threading"></li>
   <li id="nails"></li>
   <li id="makeup"></li>
   <li id="hair"></li>
   <li id="courses"></li>
   <li id="bespoke"></li> 
   </ul>

    #content #treatments li {
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #777;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    behavior: url(/scipts/PIE.php);
    }
```

Comment: Please create a simplified test case. Your current test case does not contain enough information to help. Simply put, it *should* work.

Comment: It's working on Chrome and FF for me. Can't test on IE9, don't have it on my work XP machine...http://jsfiddle.net/MYTRe/

Answer (score 4):

Be sure that the margin of <li> is not set to zero.

The box-shadow is rendered in the margin. No margin -> no shadow.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any issues with using `box-shadow` on `li` elements since `box-shadow` can be applied to all elements. [Here's](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow) the section on `box-shadow` on the W3C site.

Comment: I'm viewing in Safari. The test page is here. http://spabycar.4pixels.com, but still no luck. Assuming it should work (thanks for making that clear), I'll just have to delve deeper into my CSS and see what's wrong (unless anyone can see anything obvious in from my link)

Comment: ps http://spabycar.4pixels.com/test.html works, so it must be a conflict in the css. Just need to find it.

Comment: @AndyNightingale It looks like it's working fine, it's just not easily distinguishable from the background - change the shadow colour to `#700` and it'll be more obvious.

Comment: Yep, I can verify what @robertc said. It looks like it's working fine, it's just hard to see.

Comment: Thanks guys. I feel a right t*t now for not seeing the wood for the trees. How often you look for the most complicated solution to the simplest of problems!!

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem... box-shadow didn't work... The reason was in *rbga* instead of *rgba* in my css code! :D